# How to put text in "Say something about this..." facebook text box from android programatically

Tags: android, share, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-sharer, hint

I am sharing image on facebook from android app. I can view the image in facebook what I Shared. But, I need to write a text in "Say something" text box from android programatically. I dont no how i can achieve this via  facebook SDK. I am using facebook SDK v4.

[image]

Comment: You can not modify Facebook Dialog View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook not allow to post text either using SDK or `Intent`.

from Facebook Docs

> When you implement sharing, your app should not pre-fill any content
>   to be shared. This is inconsistent with Facebook Platform Policy, see
>   [Facebook Platform Policy, 2.3](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control).
>
> 3. Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>      parameter of posts with content a person or business didn’t create,
>      even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing. You
>      may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but
>      don't prefill any content a person or business didn't create via the
>      API.

You can specify a single **hashtag** to appear with a shared photo, link, or video. This hashtag also appears in the Share dialog, and people have the the opportunity to remove it before publishing.

The following is an example of adding a hashtag to a link share.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
    .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
            .setHashtag("#ConnectTheWorld")
            .build());
    .build();
```

Note: This(Hashtag) Additional Feature only available when you are using Facebook [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#share_dialog).

For more details, please refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: The _Say something about this…_ text is not the actual message, it is just a placeholder the input field shows before the user types any text. I assume OP here wants to achieve the same, not to prefill the actual text of the post.

Comment: @CBroe  "I need to write a text in "Say something" text box from android programmatically." , answered with this context.

Comment: You’re right, on reading it again it really sounds like they want to prefill. I assumed they just wanted a different placeholder text.

Comment: @gopal_patil, CBroe, I am having "This is my post" in string variable. I want to automatically fill this text in "Say something about this.." textbox. Is this possible. From gopal_patil point of view, this is not possible. Am I right?

Comment: it is not just a point of view, This is what facebook allow us, please check  [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control)

Comment: It says don't prefill with content the user didn't create. Ok, but how about content the user DID create? I show them a box on my website, they type in the box - they created the content. Now how to I post that content to FB?

Comment: Does this rule apply to Messenger too?